# mark list of items in string without overlap

Tags: perl, text-processing

I have a sample of text:

```
my $text = 'a bb cc xx aa a b c a';
```

and a list of terms that might be in the text:

```
my @words = ('bb cc',
    'a bb cc',
    'xx aa a b',
    'a b',
    'a'
);
```

I need to find the occurrences of these words, using the longest matches possible, and not marking anything twice. So if I marked the matches in the text above, it would look like this:

```
<a bb cc> <xx aa a b> c <a>
```

Notice that I did not mark `bb cc`, because that is part of the larger match `a bb cc`.

Any ideas on a way to do this? I feel like it should have been encountered many times before.

Comment: You can filter out `@words` comparing it against $text, and then filter out remaining overlapping `@words` elements.

Comment: Do you want to find a good algorithm to find a solution, or a solution that just works with the regex engine? Also, how do you count longest matches? Consider you have to find the strings `ab`, `ac` and `cab` in `acab`: with `<ac><ab>` you would have found a solution where the sum of the matches is longest, whereas with `a<cab>` you'd have found one where the longest match is applied first.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Longest match would be a<cab>. I guess ties could be broken alphabetically. I think I'd like the simplest solution possible, but all solutions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple substitution should do, you'll have to sort by length:

```
my $re = '('.join('|', sort {length $b <=> length $a} map(quotemeta,@words)).')';
$text =~ s/$re/<$1>/g;
say $text;
```

Output as expected for 5.20.2, can't check other version right now.
The `quotemeta` part isn't actually needed for the examples you gave, it's there to escape characters with special meaning in the regexen.

Comment: I think I overthought this. Your example almost works; @words needs to be sorted by length. Apparently the engine isn't as greedy as we thought! If `@words` contains `('a', 'a b')` and the text is `a b`, then the match will be `<a> b`. Making `@words` into `('a b', 'a')` makes it match correctly as `<a b>`.

Comment: I had used the wrong tests to check if the engine is greedy. Of course it checks left-first. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: By the way, I think my own pitfall for using regex for this was doing `while(s///g){}`, which ends up with nested tags. Adding a `c` flag fixes this.

Comment: @NateGlenn You can get rid of the while, it applies the loop until no replacement can be found. The `s///g` operator returns the number of replacements. If you add a `c` flag, the loop runs exactly once– you could as well have put an `if` there.

Comment: Ah, yes, but I am doing other processing of the matches inside of the while loop.

Comment: then use the `/e` flag, it changes the second part from doubly quoted string to code.